# How to get anchor property in controller?

Tags: spring-mvc

How can I set an anchor properties and get the properties in the controller?

I am trying to format an anchor properties so that when the user click on, I can get those properties to apply narrow searching

I am trying to format the anchor like this"

```
<a href="report/2014/search=?month=2&day=12&category=car" />
```

So I try something like this but it doesn't work:

```
@RequestMappring(value="/report/{year}/search", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String narrowSearch(@PathVariable("year")int year, @RequestParam("month") int month, @RequestParam("day) int day, @RequestParam("category") String category) {

   return "report";
}
```

May someone show me the correct way to format anchor property and retrieve in in the controller please? Thank you.

Comment: How about

href="report/2014/search?month=2&day=12&category=car"

Comment: And you are missing a quotation mark in @RequestParam("day).

Comment: Tbh it's a pretty useless question and answer, so I think, the best is if you delete it.